# Team Build 2010: Write to text file using WF

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm interested in appending some arbitrary information to a text file during a Team Build execution, however I don't have a lot of experience with Windows Workflow. My options seem to be:

- Write my own CodyActivity and import into my process template.
- Perhaps call some .NET IO methods inside an InvokeMethod activity.
- Use some sort of File-specific activity library I don't know about?

I'd like to keep this as close to "pure" WF as possible for maintenance and portability purposes, but I'm not sure where to start. It seems like there should be activities already for things as basic as file IO, but I haven't found them yet. Do these exist? If not, is something like this possible with InvokeMethod, or do I have to write my own activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use WriteToFile activity from [TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/documentation). [Here is documentation](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20WriteToFile%20build%20activity&referringTitle=Documentation) how to use it.

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I was looking for. I'm going to have to re-examine my googling methodologies. Thanks!